# Where could I find the apis or guide to apply "Share" Action on Push Notification on Android

Tags: android, push-notification, android-actionbar

So I'm trying to fiddle around with push notification, and couldn't find any leads to implement the "Share" Action on push Notification on the Android platform. Any ideas on how I could do something similar to the images below.

Thanks in advance!

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9HH4n.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's just a action to a Notification. You can add such action where you create your notification in GCM Intent Service by adding `NotificationCompact.Builder.addAction()` and attaching a PendingIntent with Share action.

If you want to share a Image as shown in the screenshot, Make sure you store the image in a bitmap and then share the path of the bitmap while sharing

Comment: Your welcome :) Mark as correct if this solved your problem so that others can refer